# Extends LDAP Read Only WSO2

Tags: mysql, ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Products, IS and API Gateway. 
My use case is : I have a ReadOnly LDAP User Store that have some attributes such name, surname, email etc.. Obviously in LDAP Read Only i can't add new user's property, for example I would like to add a attribute (claime) with name "Profile". I found some documentation but i don't understand how to do this. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manage).

If I understand well, I have to create a new User Store (such MYSQL DB) where i can mapping the LDAP's users and i can also add custom attribute. 
This is the right way to do it?

And another question is : If the consideration above is right, How can I do provisioning of the 2 User Store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it without any code is as follows.

1. Create a new claim in WSO2 according to your preference, e.g. "Profile".
2. Map this claim to an existing unused attribute of your ReadOnly LDAP.
   e.g. Map **profile** to **FAX** or **Street Addres** etc.
3. Modify configuration of your service provider and send this new claim in authentication response to your service provider.
4. Now you can update this LDAP attribute with whatever value you want and Service Provider will receive this as claim named as "profile".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this a workaround? Anyway, i don't have a Service Provider, but i have a Primary LDAP Read Only and a list of other User Stores.

Comment: Yes, it was a workaround. You do not neec to create a user store to get custom claims. Other solution is, you can create a custom cliam handler with your own logic to get claims from any external source( like MySQL or call any service etc.).